# Not all columns display when I type df.columns in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I wish to have the percent and type displayed. The code works well except when I type df.columns ,  both columns (Type and Percent) are not listed.

**Data**

```
Type                                   

Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A    
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.B    
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E    
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C    
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A   
Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A
```

**Desired**

```
Type                                    Percent

Hello-HEL-HE-12T                        50%
Hello-HEL-HE-50T                        33%
Happy-HAP-HA-90T                        16.6%
```

**Doing**

```
df.columns = ['Type']
df['computer.u_sku'] = df['computer.u_sku'].apply(lambda x: extract_value(x))                         
df1 = (df['Type'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100).to_frame('Percent')              
print(df1.rename_axis(index='Type').reset_index())
```

**Outcome**

```
    Type                                    Percent
    
    Hello-HEL-HE-12T                        50%
    Hello-HEL-HE-50T                        33%
    Happy-HAP-HA-90T                        16.6%
```

However, when I type in:

***df.columns***   , the output only lists Percent as a column. How would I have the code display both columns. I am thinking this may have something to do with setting the index. I am researching this. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
Index(['Percent'], dtype='object')
```

I have tried this:

```
df2.columns = ['Type', 'Percent'], but I get a length mismatch error
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`

Comment: ok thank you- would I type this code in before the main code? - I have tried this pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) but do not see a change.

Comment: I haven't used pandas in a while, anyway try just after when you import the libraries